# How to know the state of scroll in FlatList?

Tags: react-native

How to know the state of scroll in FlatList?
Such as startScroll、Scrolling、endScroll

```
<FlatList
    onScroll={(e) => { }}
/>
```

there is onScroll mothed,but it only run when Scrolling.
I want to listen scroll start and end,how can i do ?

I also tried use TouchableWithoutFeedback:

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback
    onPressIn={() => console.log('in')}
    onPressOut={() => console.log('out')}>
    <View><FlatList/></View>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

But touch events will be intercepted by TouchableWithoutFeedback,
FlatList can't scroll.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

since `Flatlist` inherits all `ScrollView` props, you can use `onScrollEndDrag` and `onScrollBeginDrag` to solve this issue:

```
<FlatList
    onScrollEndDrag={() => console.log("end")}
    onScrollBeginDrag={() => console.log("start")}/>
```

[further information](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#onscrollbegindrag).

Comment: Thanks, these props are missing in documentation.

Comment: Thanks, it is very weird that this is not documented. I wonder if it is getting deprecated.

Comment: It's not missing from the documentation. Please take a look at the inherited props from ScrollView: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#props

Comment: FlatList onScroll event is not firing at all:

<FlatList
        keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'always'}
        data={data}
        onScroll={() => {
          Keyboard.dismiss; //FlatList is not firing onScroll event
        }}
        renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
          <ListItem item={item} index={index} />
        )}
        keyExtractor={item => item.key}
      />